# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestIdentifier

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestIdentifier
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/launcher/TestIdentifier

This is a exception when i run the test class, How to deal with this question?

Comment: Please provide relevant code and your effort in the question. See the minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.